# In the siunitx package, how do I get it to separate the uncertainty's exponent?

Tags: siunitx

I want to have `\num{1.4 \pm .7 e5}` look more like

[image: 1.4 * 10^5 +- 0.7 * 10^5]

Instead of like

[image: (1.4 +- 0.7) * 10^5]

I couldn't find a switch for this in the [SIunitx documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf). 
Is it possible to make SIunitx typeset numbers like this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty = true}
\begin{document}
  \num{1.4 \pm 0.7 e5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure that your requested style is very popular/frequent and I doubt that `siunitx` supports this, but maybe I am wrong in this

Comment: You can't find it as it's not there: the uncertainty will be _out and out misleading_ if the exponent is different from the main value (plus I can't find an input form I feel would work at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarizing the comments from above: there is no such option in `siunitx`. If you want to use this syntax, you will have to write your own command. E.g. like:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty = true}
\newcommand*{\mynum}[3]{$\num{#1}\times\num{#3}\pm\num{#2}\times\num{#3}$}

\begin{document}
\num{1.4 \pm .7 e5}

\mynum{1.4}{.7}{e5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using this inside math mode will lead to *interesting* results. :-) I'd recommend leaving the dollar signs out of the definition and requiring the user to enter/exit math mode as needed.